# How do I rate limit mysqldump from a remote host?

Tags: mysql, rate-limiting

I'm running mysqldump from a remote machine to do periodic backups of our database and want to ensure it isn't using up all of the available bandwidth.

The command I'm running is:

```
mysqldump --compress --opt --add-drop-database --skip-lock-tables --single\
-transaction -u$USER -p$PASSWD -h $HOST $DB > $SCRIPT_DIR/$DB.$HOST_NAME\
.sql
```

I'd rather not have to rely on running the backups locally and using SCP/SFTP if possible.

Comment: something like this maybe? http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187

Comment: <ung>Iptables?</ung> I think the universe just shuddered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle) looks like it'll do the trick.

The nice thing about this is it doesn't require root credentials to work.